# Is there a "MonadThrow" with an explicit error type?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass

Is there a class somewhere on Hackage like this? I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

```
class (Typeable e, Monad m) => MonadThrow e m where
  throw :: forall a. e -> m a
```

Here's some instances:

```
instance Typeable e => MonadThrow e (Either e) where
  throw = Left

instance (Typeable e, Monad m) => MonadThrow e (EitherT e m) where
  throw = hoistEither . throw
```

Note that:

1. Unlike [`MonadThrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.5/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadThrow) in the package [`exceptions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.5), the error type is not lost by effectively mushing it into a string.
2. Unlike [`MonadError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:MonadError) in the package [`mtl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3), there is no functional dependency from `m -> e`, and we are also not required to implement [`catchError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#v:catchError).

---

**Why?**

Consider:

```
data ErrorA = ErrorA ... deriving Show
data ErrorB = ErrorB ... deriving Show
data Result
data Input

x :: Input
x = ...

f :: (MonadThrow ErrorA m, MonadThrow ErrorB m) => Input -> m Result
```

I can then do either:

```
data ErrorAOrB = IsErrorA ErrorA | IsErrorB ErrorB

newtype IsErrorAOrB result = IsErrorAOrB (Either ErrorAOrB result) deriving Monad

instance MonadThrow ErrorA IsErrorAOrB where
  throw = IsErrorAOrB . Left . IsErrorA

instance MonadThrow ErrorB IsErrorAOrB where
  throw = IsErrorAOrB . Left . IsErrorB

y :: IsErrorAOrB Result
y = f x
```

and actually retain the type information. Or alternatively, if I just want to squash any error into a string:

```
newtype ErrorString result = ErrorString (Either String result) deriving Monad

instance Show errorType => MonadThrow errorType ErrorString where
  throw = Left . show

y :: ErrorString Result
y = f x
```

Noting that couldn't do either of the above [`MonadError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:MonadError) due to the functional dependency, and whilst the standard [`MonadThrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.5/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadThrow) class permits the second approach of squashing everything into a string at the call site, it doesn't give anyway of retaining the error types like in the first approach.

Note also if I instead had all my error types being instances of `ToJSON`, instead of `Show` (which might be more useful in a webapp) then I could do:

```
newtype ErrorJSON result = ErrorJSON (Either JSON.Value result) deriving Monad

instance ToJSON errorType => MonadThrow errorType ErrorString where
  throw = Left . toJSON

y :: ErrorJSON Result
y = f x
```

I like this structure because I can defer my choice of strongly typed or weakly typed errors to the call site. And by avoiding a bunch of different `EitherT`s inside my code, this simplifies composition because my logic is all operating in one general Monad `m`, with the choice of it's implementation outside of that logic. However, I couldn't see anything on Hackage implementing such a scheme. Have I just missed something? Or is this approach novel? Or is it just a bad idea for some reason I haven't realised (perhaps there's something simpler I should do to achieve the same)?

Comment: Why not do `MonadError (Either ErrorA ErrorB) m`? This reminds me of `(MonadState A m, MonadState B m)` vs `MonadState (A, B) m`, but I don't really know what the best solution to that is either.

Comment: @Noughtmare the problem with that is that each `throw` would need to explicitly construct the `Left` or `Right` case, i.e. it would need to know all the options for what there is to be thrown. Whereas with `(MonadThrow ErrorA, MonadThrow ErrorB)` you could just have one function that throws an `ErrorA`, one that throws an `ErrorB`, combine both of them together without explicitly having to adapt each, and it's up to the caller to decide whether to handle the various errors separately or just displaying them in a catch-all fashion (by selecting a concrete monad).

Comment: @leftaroundabout but you can work around that by introducing a second type class that does the injection. I believe an advantage of splitting it into two type classes like that is that you only have to write n + m instances (n error types; m error monads) while the single type class approach proposed in this question requires n × m instances: one for each combination of error type and error throwing monad.